# WinUI 3, Desktop application error during "Package and Publish"

Tags: c#, multithreading, xaml, winui-3, zstd

[image: Image of the Error]

I'm working on a WinUI 3 desktop application. During the option of "Package and Publish", I get an error of which I've attached the image (as the error details are too long, I thought of adding it as an image).

It seems there is an error while trying to optimize some assemblies.

PS: I used the ([WinUI 3 template](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TemplateStudio.TemplateStudioForWinUICs)) to create the project.

Things I've tried:

I set the "PublishReadyToRun" to "false", in the csproj file, however this did not help.

Comment: How can I reproduce your issue?

Comment: Please don't add as an image. It's hard for us to search for the details from an image.

Comment: Please read [ask] and also provide us with a [mcve] that reproduces the problem. Good questions get answers within minutes of posting.

Comment: The image should be shared as screenshot instead of attached image. It would be difficult to move back and forth in the tabs when we want to answer any question.

Comment: @RohanRao - Please don't recommend images at all please unless the text is there in the question itself.

Comment: @Enigmativity, Images are necessary to understand exactly what error the OP have come across. Will help others who will answer the question though. I have recommended OP to post the image as screenshot so that it will have the error displayed clearly instead of pasting it as attached image, and we don't have to look back and forth the browser tabs which is a pain most of the times.

Comment: @RohanRao - Please don't recommend images at all unless the text is already in the question. There is no difference in my mind between a "screenshot" and an "image" - can you clarify what you see as the difference? Images should only be added to supplement the text already in the question.

Comment: @OmkarD I cannot reproduce it. Did it run successfully in the Visual Studio? It could be related to your environment, and you can file an issue in the [WindowsAppSDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/deploy-packaged-apps#address-installation-errors) or [TemplateStudio](https://github.com/microsoft/TemplateStudio/issues) GitHub repo with the error code and event logs so that we can investigate the issue.